# How to run a script located in a subdirectory? ImportError: No module named x

Tags: python, scripting, directory

My directory structure:

```
r/
 |___init__.py
 |
 |_d1/
 |   |___init__.py
 |   |_s1.py
 |
 |_d2/
     |___init__.py
     |_s2.py
```

contents of s1.py:

```
a = 1

print(a)
```

contents of s2.py:

```
from d1.s1 import a

print(2 * a)
```

I navigate to directory `/r` and execute `python3 d1/s1.py`. Terminal prints `1`. When I execute `python3 d2/s2.py` I get an error `ImportError: No module named 'd1'`. How to execute script `s2`?

Answer (score 1):

When you say,

```
from d1.s1 import a
```

Python will start by looking for a module named d1, and then inside that a module named s1, and then inside that for an object named a(which may be a regular python object, or another module).

So,

```
from d1.s1 import a
```

could work in a few different ways:

```
-- d1/
    -- __init__.py
      -- s1.py          <-- contains a variable called "a"
```

or

```
- d1/
    -- __init__.py
    -- s1/
        -- __init__.py
        -- a.py
```

or

```
-- d1/
|    -- __init__.py
    -- s1/
        -- __init__.py     <-- contains a variable called "a"
```

in your case **init**.py works only when d1 and s1 and s2 are in same directories.

If you want to import module s1 from another sub directory d1, make sure the directory d1 in sys path.

To add d1 to sys path

```
sys.path.append('path_to_directory/d1')
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. How do I make it work the way it is? I.e. being in /r I execute some command and the script s2.py works? Typically I have similar folder structure with d2 being tests. When I do `python3 -m unittest discover` it somehow knows how to do the imports.

Comment: @wtaga Then, directories r/d1 is not in sys.path